# Valuative criterion for properness up to extensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Given a morphism $f : X\rightarrow Y$ of schemes of finite type, the usual valuative criterion for properness says that if for every valuation ring $R$ with fraction field $K$, and commuting morphisms $\text{Spec K}\rightarrow\text{Spec }R\rightarrow Y$ and $\text{Spec }K\rightarrow X\rightarrow Y$, then there is a unique map $\text{Spec }R\rightarrow X$ making the resulting diagram commute, then $f$ is proper.

Now suppose instead we assume that $f$ is of finite type, and for every valuation ring $R$ with fraction field $K$ admitting maps as above, there exists a field extension $K'/K$ with a valuation ring $R'\subset K'$ dominating $R$ with the property that $f$ satisfies the usual valuative criterion with respect to $R',K'$. Is this 'weakened' valuative criterion (ie, valuative criterion up to extensions) actually equivalent to the original one?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are equivalent for schemes. The weaker notion is necessary when working with algebraic spaces or stacks ([Example](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03KI)) and the equivalence is proven [Here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ARH).