# Confusion regarding valuative criteria for proper maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, algebraic-stacks

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a proper morphism of schemes i.e. universally closed, finite type, separated.
Then the valuative criteria states that it is iff the condition that given a commutative diagram of maps from a valuation ring $specR \to Y$ and its fraction field $specK \to X$ there exists a unique lift $specR \to X$.

Now in the valuative criteria for proper maps between Deligne Mumford stacks (following Jarod Alper's notes available online and on YouTube) he says the criteria is there is a lift after possibly an extension $specR' \to specR$ to some other valuation ring and its fraction field.

So this should obviously hold at the level of schemes too.

> Question : For schemes if there is a lift after extension to a new valuation ring, why is there an extension for the original valuation ring?

Comment: I guess the idea is that the property of a morphism to be proper descends in the etale topology.

Comment: See [Stacks 0ARH](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ARH) as referenced in [Valuative criterion for properness up to extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289801/valuative-criterion-for-properness-up-to-extensions?rq=1), a question linked on the "Related" section of this page.